# how to list my ERC 20 token on etherscan.io/token

Tags: solidity, erc20

I am learning solidity and as a part of that developed a ERC20 token and deployed the same on Rinkeyby testnet via Remix.

Contract code is as given below

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract TestCoin is ERC20 {
    constructor() public ERC20("TestCoin", "TCN"){
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000000000000000);
    }
}
```

I can see my contract deployed on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/:contract-address. But my token is not showing up on
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/:contract-address

Is this just a testnet thing or I need to take some additional steps for it to appear on /token

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with rinkeby network, I usually test on ropsten. But as far as I am concerned, you can try verifying the smart contract on etherscan.